# Sequence exists but I can't find it in information_schema.sequences (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, database-sequence

I have created a sequence (let's call it **my_seq**) in a schema (let's call it **my_schema**) of my PostgreSQL (version 13) database. I am sure the sequence exists because I can find it in the result set of the query

```
select n.nspname as sequence_schema, 
       c.relname as sequence_name
from pg_class c 
  join pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.relnamespace
where c.relkind = 'S'
and n.nspname = 'my_schema'
```

However, if I run the following query

```
select sequence_name 
from information_schema.sequences 
where sequence_schema = 'my_schema'
```

my_seq isn't in the result set.
I have run both queries with the same user I created the sequence with.

Can anybody help me find an explanation for this?

Answer (score 7):

The missing sequences are likely the ones used in an `Identity` column.

You can fetch all sequences using `select * from pg_sequences;`

To answer the *why* of the question: `information_schema.sequences` is a view, you can see its definition by running `\d+ information_schema.sequences`. There, we can see that it filters out objects being an [internal dependency](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-depend.html) (`AND NOT (EXISTS ... AND pg_depend.deptype = 'i'`), which is the case of the sequences backing an Identity column.